# Joint density of order statistics from dependent normal random variables

Tags: joint-distribution, order-statistics, dependent-variable

Suppose that $_1,…,_$ are mutlivariate normal with correlation $\rho_{ij}$ and each of them are marginally distributed as $(0,1)$. Let $_{(1)},…,_{()}$ be the corresponding order statistics.  What is the joint distribution of $_{(i)}\text{ and }_{(j)}, \text{ where }i\neq j$? Can anyone give some reference on this? Thank you!

Comment: what is an order in dimension $n$?

Answer (score 1):

If $n=2$, and $p(x,y)$ is the bivariate pdf for $X_1$ and $X_2$, then the pdf for $X_{(1)}$ and $X_{(2)}$ is
$$(p(x,y)+p(y,x))\,\mathbf{1}_{x<y}$$
In other words, it is the sum when $x<y$, and $0$ otherwise.

If $n=3$, and $p(x,y,z)$ is the multivariate pdf for $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$, then the pdf for $X_{(1)}$, $X_{(2)}$ and $X_{(3)}$ is
$$(p(x,y,z)+p(x,z,y)+p(y,x,z)+p(y,z,x)+p(z,x,y)+p(z,y,x))\,\mathbf{1}_{x<y<z}$$
In other words, it is the sum when $x<y<z$, and $0$ otherwise. You can get the joint distribution for any two of these order statistics by integrating over the third, which gives a closed-form but unenlightening expression with six uses of the normal cdf $\Phi$.

If $n\ge 4$, then the distribution over $X_{(1)}, \ldots, X_{(n)}$ follows the same pattern, but the joint distribution of $X_{(i)}$ and $X_{(j)}$ probably has no closed-form expression.